# Eclipse shows no resource leak when a Scanner is a static class variable - Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, garbage-collection

Let's suppose I am using a Scanner as a static, class-level variable:

```java
public class Demo {

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

I know it's a good practice to close your Scanner class whenever you open one - or use try-with-resources -, but apparently my Eclipse does not indicate that this one should be closed if it's a static field. If I put it into a method as a local variable, then Eclipse automatically gives me a warning that I should close my Scanner to avoid resource leaks.

I know that while the class is loaded, GC will not get rid of any of the fields, but it would not be able to get rid of Scanner anyway, would it?

So my question is: does Eclipse have a specific reason that it does not indicate that I could close a Scanner if it's a class variable, or it's just a fault of the IDE instead? What do you think?

Comment: Because it will never go out of scope; also `System.in` is a global. Closing a scanner wrapping `System.in` is a bad idea.

Comment: Seemingly it works in the same way with any type of InputStream implementations:

static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] {}));  --> it produces the same result.

Anyhow, I feel it makes sense not to close a global, class-level variable, I just thought there might have been a more specific answer I was not aware of.

Comment: And a `static` field is a global, class level variables; so it makes sense to you why eclipse doesn't warn you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine it to be like explicit type casts, the *developer knows what he is doing* and the validation behind the scenes has no way of checking if you need that scanner to not be closed or not at a specific point in time you dereference it, since the field is static.

However, what the validation can do it to validate if all resources you declared (and that need to be closed) in the current scope are indeed closed. Also, the `try-with-resources` construct only works with local variables as mentioned in the JLS, [Section 14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3).